# how to embed a watermark on pdf files with more than one page with image-watermark

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, next.js, watermark

as the title says i'm trying to figure out how to embed a watermark on every page of a pdf file using image-watermark library.
Actually i'm only able to add a text watermark on file with only one page so i'm wondering if there's a possibility to accomplish this task.

Here's my code with a destination path and a response to the client with the link to download

```
let optionsWatermark = {
        'text': 'testo di prova',
        'color' : 'rgb(154, 50, 46)',
        'dstPath': `public/watermarked/${pdf}`
    }
    watermark.embedWatermark(`public/uploads/${pdf}`, optionsWatermark)
        
    res.status(200).json({
        data: 'Watermark added correctly',
        link: `/watermarked/${pdf}`
    })
    console.log('Your watermark has been added successfully')
```

Comment: thanks for the reply i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a water mark to multiple pages using your `image-watermark` library. You could [convert each page into an image](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/11/20/convert_pdf_to_image_imagemagick/), apply the watermark, [then re-create a new pdf using those images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493584/convert-images-to-pdf) though.

Comment: thanks, this answer really helped me a lot figuring it out how to solve the problem.